# In this quote from Bitbucket, what is the difference between "source" and "your update", and between "destination", and "original code"?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, pull-request

I'm reading about resolving merge conflicts in Bitbucket here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-merge-conflicts-704414003.html
It says "When you create a pull request Bitbucket automatically compares the source with your update and the destination with the original code".

My current understanding is that when you do a pull request, you're merging the 'source' into the 'destination'. I assumed that the 'source' is that same as 'your update' and that the 'destination' is the same as the 'original code'.

**My question is:** What is the difference between all these terms? Specifically, what's the difference between 'source' and 'your update', and what's the difference between 'destination' and 'original code'?

Comment: Tried to read this and help; that sentence in the docs is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It's not at all clear to me why they are inventing terms and then not defining them properly.  It's true that pull requests themselves are fairly complex, so trying to explain how pull requests work, one might well define one's own terms.  But, having done so, one should then actually *define* them, not just use them and hope. :-)

Since this answer is not very useful—it just amounts to me saying "I don't know what **they** mean"—let's try a different tack, and take a look at pull requests in general.

Caveat: **Pull requests are not a Git thing, they're a web-hosting-service thing, and every web-hosting-service may do something slighlty different here.**  I'm a bit biased towards GitHub rather than Bitbucket as all of my Git experience is with GitHub (I did use Bitbucket a little bit for Mercurial, many years ago).  In this case, though, I believe Bitbucket have a very similar implementation.

#### Merging

Before we cover pull requests, we should have a brief look at merging in Git.  It's important to realize that `git merge` does not always actually merge.  Sometimes it does what Git calls a *fast-forward* instead.  It can also be instructed to do unusual things, e.g., `git merge -s ours` makes a *merge commit* without actually doing any *merging*.  As such, we need to split the word *merge* into its two main meanings:

- *To merge*, or *merge as a verb*, is the action of combining changes.
- *A merge*, or *a merge commit*, which uses the word *merge* as an adjective or noun, is a Git commit that has two or more *parents*.  Most commits have exactly one parent, and most of the rest have exactly two.  The parent of a commit—or parents, for merges—tell Git which commit, by commit-hash-ID, comes *before* this particular commit.

When you have a simple linear sequence of commits, each with one parent, the result is a nice simple backwards-looking chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H ...
```

where the commit with hash `H` lists hash ID `G` as its parent, so that commit `H` *points to* commit `G`.  Meanwhile `G` points to `F`.  `F` points to some earlier commit, and so on.  This is how Git forms branches: a *branch name* like `master` simply contains the raw hash ID of the *last* commit.  If that's commit `H`, for instance, the name `master` contains the hash ID of `H`.  From there, Git finds `G`, then `F`, then `E`, and so on (assuming the commits are in alphabetical order).

The whole thing stops when Git reaches a commit with *no* parent.  The very first commit anyone ever makes in a new, empty repository has no parent, since there was no previous commit to mention.  Later commits do have a parent: the commit that *was* the tip of the branch, before you made the then-new commit, is the parent of the commit you made.  So in general, branches grow simply by making a new commit: you `git checkout` that branch to get "on" it—`git status` now says `on branch master` for instance—and then you do some work and run `git commit`.  Git makes a new commit whose parent is `H`.  If we call the new commit `I`, Git just stuffs the new hash ID of new commit `I` into the existing name `master`, and now `master` points to `I` instead of `H` and there's one more commit on the branch.

That's fine for *linear* stuff, but what happens when we want to merge?  Let's say we have:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- feature
```

We got here by creating a new name `feature`, identifying commit `H`, then making two new commits that extended it.  Meanwhile we also (probably just a bit earlier) extended `master` by creating two new commits that extended it.  So now `master` identifies—or points to—commit `J`, `feature` identifies commit `L`, and the best common *shared* commit is `H`, which is on *both* branches.

We then run:

```
git checkout master; git merge feature
```

or:

```
git checkout feature; git merge master
```

Either way, Git:

1. Finds the *merge base*, which is commit `H`: the best *shared* commit, on both branches.
2. Compares (as with `git diff --find-renames`) commit `H` to our current commit (`J` or `L`), to see what we changed on the branch we have checked-out.
3. Compares (as with `git diff --find-renames`) commit `H` (again) to the other commit (`L` or `J`), to see what *they* changed on their branch.
4. Attempts to *combine* these changes.  If the combining works, Git applies the *combined* changes to the *merge base* version of each file.  That *keeps* what we changed, and *adds to it*, whatever they changed, too.
5. If all goes well in this combining, makes a new commit with two parents—a merge commit.  The two parents are *our* commit—whichever branch we checked out—and *their* commit, in that order.  That is, the *first* parent is the same one as usual for *any* new commit; the *second* parent is the other commit, that we named by saying `git merge _____`.

Assuming we're doing all this with the `git checkout master; git merge feature` arrangement, we get:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master
         \    /
          K--L   <-- feature
```

and our name `master` now points to new commit `M`.

#### Pull requests are (usually) *like* merges, only fancier,  with a lot of repositories

To do the `git merge` above, we had to have *all* the commits in *our* repository.  We don't have to have a *name* for "their" commit.  We did in the example; we called it `feature`.  That makes things easier.  But we *do* have to have their commit—we have to have commit `L`, and its parent `K`, and the common commit `H`, and of course our own two commits `I` and `J`, to make this all work.

If all the work happened in our own repository, there is no problem here: we *do* have all the commits already, plus branch names to find them.  But what if we did *our* work (on our `master`, or maybe on our `feature`) but *they*—whoever they are—used a *different* repository to do their work?

Any time you get a web hosting provider involved, whether it's GitHub or Bitbucket or GitLab or whoever, *they* have *their* Git repositories.  There's a Git repo on GitHub or Bitbucket.  It might be *delegated to* you, as in, you can use the web interface to do whatever they'll let you do *to* it, but it's still *their* repository.

If you're in a team, with collaborators or co-workers, there may well be even more repositories involved.  Let's look first at the situation where you and your co-workers have a (work-provided, work-managed) web-hosting-provider repository that you all *share*.  We'll give two people at work names, as well: [Alice](https://xkcd.com/177/) and [Bob](https://xkcd.com/1323/).  We'll give the web-hosting-provider the name W.  (There's no [Eve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) this time.)  You'll play the part of Alice here.

We start with some existing repository **W** (hosted on GitHub or Bitbucket).  You—Alice—make a *clone* of this repository, creating **A**.  Bob makes a clone, creating **B**.  Both clones have commits up through `H`.  *Commits* are what get shared across clones—branch names *can* be different, but the commits are always shared, and all Gits everywhere agree as to their raw hash IDs.

Now you make your two new commits, which we'll call `I` and `J`.  It doesn't really matter what branch name *you* use here, but let's just call it branch `alice` for simplicity.  Repo **A** has `I` and `J`, plus the shared commits through `H`.

Meanwhile, Bob makes his two new commits, which we'll call `K` and `L`.  We'll call this branch `bob`; repo **B** has `K` and `L`, plus the shared commits through `H`.

At this point, you can `git push -u origin alice` to send commits `I` and `J` to repo **W**.  They'll take the new commits, and create a new-to-them branch name `alice` to remember commit `J`.  Meanwhile Bob can `git push -u origin bob` to send commits `K` and `L` to **W**.

Now, someone *at* **W**—a human in control of this repository—*could*, at this point, take control of it and directly advance *their* `master` to either `J` or `L`, and then `git merge` the other commit.  But in general, nobody actually sits at the computers at the web hosting site.  So you—Alice—have to do something to convince someone to incorporate *your* commit `K`.

Having already sent your commits to repo **W**, and given them the name `alice` there, you can now create a *pull request* directly on repo **W** itself.  This pull request will, for instance, say "Alice wants to merge commit(s) from `alice` into `master`".  Bob can do the same with his branch `bob` there.

The actual merging may get done by some third person, or maybe Bob can merge your commit and you can merge his.  In either case, it's likely to go one at a time—and whoever does it, using whatever web interface, may force a real merge for the first one.  Let's say the first one is yours, and supervisor Carol does the merge.  This is what's in the repository at **W** *before* Carol does her thing using the web interface:

```
          I--J   <-- alice
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- bob
```

Afterward, repo **W** looks like this:

```
          I--J   <-- alice
         /    \
...--G--H------M   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- bob
```

where the first parent of `M` is `H`, and the second parent of `M` is `J`.  Carol can now merge Bob's commit, making a *second* merge commit `N`:

```
          I--J   <-- alice
         /    \
...--G--H------M--N   <-- master
         \       /
          K-----L   <-- bob
```

At this point, the *names* `alice` and `bob` can be safely deleted (by you and Bob, or by Carol), as all the commits are now safely find-able by starting at `N` and working backwards.

#### This simple kind of pull request is simpler than the typical real one

To get to this point, you had to run `git push` to the—single—common starting repository **W**.  Bob ran `git push` to the same common starting repository.  Then, someone with control over that starting repository **W** used the web interface to really make both merges.

All of this also assumed that all the merges *worked*.  Using `git merge` locally, in your own repository, only makes a new merge commit (in step 5 above) if the merge *succeeds*.  To make that part happen properly, the web hosting provider actually ran a *test merge* at the time you said: *Make this pull request.*  If the test merge *fails*, the hosting provider might prohibit the pull request.  GitHub allows it while marking it not-actually-merge-able, so that others can look at the commits *on* GitHub, in repository **W** itself, and even bring them to their own repositories if they know how.

But in some cases, you're not *allowed* to push directly to repository **W**.  Suppose you *aren't* a co-worker and there isn't a single shared common repository **W**.  Instead, there is some open-source repository **R**.  You can *read* from **R** but not write to it.  So you create a *fork*.

A fork is really just a clone on the web hosting site, but with an extra feature.  You create your fork—let's call it **RA** for Alice's **R**—on site W.  Repo **RA** has *its own branches*, which hosting site W has set up as copies of those in **R**, with all the commits also copied from **R**.  (Secretly, behind the scenes, the actual commits are almost certainly shared.  This sharing gets complicated and I don't know what exact tricks the various web hosting providers use.  However, because commit hash IDs are universally the same in all Gits, it doesn't matter, except in terms of disk space, whether they're shared or copied.)

You now clone repository **RA** instead of repository **R**.  So your repository **A** has **RA** as its `origin`.  You make your two commits—`I` and `J` as before—in **A**.  Then you use `git push -u origin name` to send your branch *`name`* to **RA**.  It doesn't matter what branch name you use here, because **RA** is not **R**: each repository has *its own* branch names.

You're now ready to make a pull request.  To do this, you use the web interface to manipulate **RA**.  You click on some button, select whatever branch name you are using in **RA**, and select the branch and the repository in **R** where you'd like to ask *them*—the people who control **R**—to merge your commits into *their* repository.  The web hosting provider at W checks whether this merge would work: it *copies* your commits `I` and `J` into *their* repository **R**, but not on any branch at all.<sup>1</sup>  Site W tests whether the merge would work, and then lets you proceed to make the pull request.

(If some guy Bob even exists, and he's going to make pull requests, he probably makes his own fork **RB**.  Then he has to clone his fork, and repeat the above, more or less.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The actual reference here is, for GitHub, `refs/pull/number/head`.  Bitbucket use a somewhat different non-branch reference, [`refs/pull-requests/number/from`](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Difference-of-refs-pull-requests-lt-ID-gt-merge-and-refs-pull/qaq-p/772142).  Note that these reference names appear in **R**, not **RA**, and are subject to change.

---

#### Summary

In a typical pull request scenario, there are at least three repositories involved:

- the original (open-source-ish or whatever) repository **R**;
- your fork, which we have been calling **RA** but we can just call **F** now;
- and your clone on your computer, where you do your work.

You will `git push` *commits* (not files) from your computer to **F**, then make pull requests using **F** and its remembered (and copied-or-probably-really-shared) connection to repository **R** on the web hosting site.  From here on, everything internally works by commit hash ID, up until you need to revise your pull request.

If you *do* want to revise your pull request, you can `git push` again from your computer to your fork **F** to update a *branch name* stored in **F**.  If that branch *name* is part of the pull request, web hosting site W is likely to automatically rewrite the pull request to use the new commit(s) you sent via your new, updating `git push`.  (Technically, that's up to the hosting site W.  GitHub certainly do this and I'd be shocked if Bitbucket do not.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are breaking it in 4 parts.... but there are only 3 parts:

- the source with your update
- the destination
- the original code

Even "the source" might be affecting all 3 elements, namely, your code at the tip of the branch, the tip of the branch you want to merge into and the point where the branches started to diverge (it's a little more complex than that but that explanation gets the basics laid down).